# Facebook iFrame Vertical Scrollbar Won't Go Away

Tags: facebook, iframe, scrollbar

I created a custom facebook landing page using the same template I have used 3 times before. The problem is, this time, ther vertical scrollbar won't go away. This is the resizing code I have been using:

```
<script type="text/javascript">// <![CDATA[
    window.fbAsyncInit = function() { FB.Canvas.setSize({ width: 520, height: 1200});}
    function sizeChangeCallback() { FB.Canvas.setSize({ width: 520, height: 1200});}
// ]]></script>
```

and at the bottom of the page:

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script src="http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">// <![CDATA[
    FB.init({
    appId : 'MY_APP_ID',
    status : true, // check login status
    cookie : true, // enable cookies to allow the server to access the session
    xfbml : true // parse XFBML
    });
// ]]></script>
```

My CSS uses `body {overflow: hidden;}`, inside my app "auto resize" is selected. The issue is not that the ifarme won't resize (it does), it's that I have an empty vertical scrollbar on the right that won't go away.

Since the iframe design uses the whole 520px width, the empty vertical srollbar gives me the dreaded horizontal scrollbar. Judging by the width of the horizontal scrollbar, it's the vertical scrollbar causing it and not anything (that I can find or see) in the HTML/CSS making the page wider than 520px. The problem happens in IE8, IE7 and Firefox.

You can see the page [here](http://www.facebook.com/pages/BestAbMachineX/107357052688887).

I have tried a few variations of the javascript code from a few different sources, but no luck. Not sure if this is something small I'm missing or if it's yet another facebook bug. This problem is not present on any of my other facebook iframe landing pages. After searching around for an answer and coming up with nothing, I've hit a wall with this one.

Comment: all old. All wrong. You can't use CSS alone.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Its this code

```
html {
overflow-Y: scroll;
}
```

in your style.css style sheet thats causing the problem.  When I inspect it with Chrome and remove that value, the scroll bars disappear.

Comment: Outstanding! That fixed it. 
Thank you bkaid!

Comment: For anyone who's curious, that CSS was part of an accordion content holder that I didn't end up using... deleted the whole section and the scrollbar problem disappeared.

Comment: I've also seen that property set by some css resets.